# Kafka producer create partition for a topic from Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am creating a kafka producer and I want to specify partitionId as well while sending the message according to the message type. I have type-partitonId mapping in my Mysql table. In case of new message type I have to create new partition and save that id to Mysql so that it can directly send message to that Id next time same type comes. How can I create new partition for a topic and get the created partitionId ? 
I am using latest kafka API .9 and Java 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the AdminUtils class, specifically at the addPartitions() method.  Note that you'll probably have to wait a while for the metadata to be propagated to all of the brokers before actually sending the message.

Comment: Thanks.. I implemented this using AdminUtils.
Please correct me if anything is wrong in the following approach.


1- AddPartion Using    AdminUtils.addPartitions(zkUtils,KAFKA_PRODUCER_TOPIC,currentPartitionCount+1,"",true);

 - This method is returning void.


2- Get the list<Partition> using producer.partitionsFor(KAFKA_PRODUCER_TOPIC) assume the first element contains newly created topic Id get it and use it to sent message.